# Parallel Implementation of DFS for undirected graph

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, algorithm, parallel-processing

I have been trying to implement a parallel Depth First Search in Java for undirected graph. I wrote this code but it doesn't work properly. It doesn't speed-up.

Main method:

```
 package dfsearch_v2;

 import java.util.Calendar;
 import java.util.Stack;
 import java.util.Random;

 public class DFSearch_v2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long ts_b, ts_e;
    int el_count=100;
    int thread_count = 4;
    int vertices[][]; // graph matrix
    boolean isVisited[] = new boolean[el_count];
    for(int i=0;i<el_count;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<el_count;j++){
            Random boolNumber = new Random();
            boolean edge = boolNumber.nextBoolean(); 
            vertices[i][j]=edge ? 1 : 
        }   
    }


    DFSTest r[] = new DFSTest[thread_count];
    ts_b = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
        r[i] = new DFSTest(el_count,vertices,isVisited);
        r[i].start();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < thread_count;    
        try {   
            r[i].join();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {

          }
    }
    ts_e = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println("Time "+(ts_e-ts_b));      
}
```

Thread implementation:

```
package dfsearch_v2;

import java.util.Stack;

public class DFSTest extends Thread {

    int numberOfNodes;
    int adj[][];
    boolean isVisit[];



public DFSTest(int numberOfNodes, int adj[][],boolean isVisit[]){
    this.numberOfNodes = numberOfNodes;
    this.adj=adj;  
    this.isVisit=isVisit;
}

public void run()
{
    int k,i,s=0;
    Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();
    for(k=0; k < numberOfNodes; k++) isVisit[k]=false;
    for (k = numberOfNodes - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        st.push(k);
    }
        DFSearch(st, isVisit);


}

   private void DFSearch(Stack<Integer> st,boolean isVisit[]){
       synchronized(isVisit){
        int i,k;
        while (!st.empty()) { 
        k=st.pop();
        if (!isVisit[k]) {
            isVisit[k] = true;
            System.out.println("Node "+k+" is visit");

            for(i=numberOfNodes-1; i>=0; i--)
                if(adj[k][i]==1) st.push(i);
        }

    }

  }

 }


}
```

Could anybody, please, help me? I am really new to parallel programming.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your program correctly, you are locking on the `isVisit` array which is shared between all threads - this means that you're not going to get any speedup because only one thread is able to make progress.  Try using a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) or [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) instead.

```
// shared between all threads
ConcurrentMap<Integer, Boolean> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public boolean isVisit(Integer integer) {
    return map.putIfAbsent(integer, Boolean.TRUE) != null;
}

private void DFSearch(Stack<Integer> st) {
    if(!isVisit(st.pop())) {
       ...
    }
}
```

The concurrent maps use sharding to increase parallelism.  Use the `putIfAbsent` method in `isVisit` to avoid a data race (you only want the method to return false for one thread).

As for how to divide the work up among multiple threads, use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` of worker threads.  When a thread has no more work to perform, it adds itself to the worker thread queue.  When a thread has two edges to traverse, it `polls` the worker thread queue for an available worker thread, and if one is available it assigns one of the edges to the worker thread.  When all threads are on the available thread queue then you've traversed the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to synchronize on *isVisit*, which is what is destroying your parallelism.  Multiple readers/multiple writers for a Boolean array should be quite safe.

If at all possible, you should avoid dependencies between threads.  To this end, don't use a shared stack (if this is what your code is doing -- it's unclear).

In your case, the amount of work done per vertex is tiny, so it makes sense to batch up work in each thread and only consider handing work on to other threads once some backlog threshold is reached.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the approach a little. Now it uses one global stack which is shared by all the threads and n local stacks where n is the number of threads. Each thread stores the nodes of its sub-tree in its local stack. Initially the global stack contains the root of the tree and only one thread gets access to it while the other threads are waiting to be woken up by the working thread. The working thread retrieves and processes the root from the global stack, adds one successor to its local stack then pushes the rest of the successors, if they exist, to the global stack to be processed by other threads and wakes up all the waiting threads. All the other threads follow the same approach (i.e. when threads get a node from the global stack they push one successor to their local stack and the rest to the global stack then start accessing their local stack until it becomes empty).

Yet, it doesn't speed up. I'll be thankful to all of your further ideas.

Main method:

```
package dfsearch_v2;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;




public class DFSearch_v2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    long ts_b, ts_e;
    //number of nodes
    int el_count=400;
int thread_count = 8;
    int gCounter=0;
    int vertices[][] = new int[el_count][el_count]; // graph matrix
    boolean isVisited[] = new boolean[el_count];

    for(int i=0;i<el_count;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<el_count;j++){
            Random boolNumber = new Random();
            boolean edge = boolNumber.nextBoolean(); 
            vertices[i][j]=edge ? 1 : 0;

        }   
    }
    DFSearch2 r[] = new DFSearch2[thread_count];
          ts_b = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
          for(int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {


            r[i] = new DFSearch2(el_count,vertices,isVisited,gCounter);
            r[i].start();

    }      
        for(int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {

        try {

            r[i].join();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

    }
         ts_e = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println("Time "+(ts_e-ts_b));              
}    
}
```

Thread implementation:

```
package dfsearch_v2;

import java.util.Stack;



public class DFSearch2 extends Thread{

private boolean isVisit[];
private final Stack<Integer> globalStack;
int numberOfNodes;
//traversal is done ?
boolean isDone;
int adj[][];
// count visited nodes
int gCounter;

public DFSearch2(int number_Nodes,int adj[][],boolean isVisit[],int gCounter){
    this.numberOfNodes=number_Nodes;
    this.isVisit = isVisit;
    this.globalStack = new Stack<>();
    this.isDone=false;
    this.adj=adj;
    this.gCounter=gCounter;
    this.globalStack.push(number_Nodes-1);

}

public void run(){

        // local stack
        Stack<Integer> localStack = new Stack<>();
        while (!isDone) { 
            int k;
            synchronized(globalStack){
             k = globalStack.pop();  
             //pop until k is not visited
             while (isVisit[k]) { 
                if(globalStack.empty()) {
                    isDone=true;
                    return;
                }else{
                    k=globalStack.pop();
                }
              }

            } 
            // traverse sub-graph with start node k
            DFSearchNode(localStack,k);
            yield();
            if(globalStack.empty()) {
               isDone = true; 
            }
            // if gCounter is not null unvisited node are pushed in globalStack
            if(isDone&&gCounter<numberOfNodes){ 
                isDone=false;
                //unvisited nodes are pushed in globalStack
                for (int i = 0; i < isVisit.length; i++) {
                    if (!isVisit[i]) {
                      globalStack.push(i);  
                    }  

                }
            }


   }


}    
 synchronized private void DFSearchNode(Stack<Integer> localStack, int k){

            localStack.push(k);

            while (!localStack.empty()) {
               int s=localStack.pop();
               if (!isVisit[s]) {
                    isVisit[s] = true;
                    gCounter++;
                    //System.out.println("Node "+s+" is visit");
                   //first element is pushed into localStack and anothers in   globalStack
                     boolean flag = true; // local or global stack (true -> local; false ->global )
                     for(int i=numberOfNodes-1; i>=0; i--)
                     {
                       //   
                       if(i==s) continue;
                       //push another successors in global stack
                       if(adj[s][i]==1&&!flag&&!isVisit[s]){//visited nodes are not pushed in globalStack
                           globalStack.push(i);
                       }
                       //push first successor  in global stack
                       if(adj[s][i]==1&&flag&&!isVisit[s]) //visited nodes are not pushed in localStack
                       {
                           localStack.push(i);
                           flag=false; //only first element is pushed into localStack
                       } 

                     }                
               }


            }

}

}
```